# How we can get custom field type which will bring custom data from custom table to use as a drop down

Tags: forms

I need to use my custom table data as a drop down.

**for eg.** i have created one custom table which is getting list of cities and i want that list to be shown in my form as a drop down.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create Custom field type you need to follow following steps

1. Create a custom module (myfield)
2. In myfield.install file add this

   ```
   /**
   * Implements hook_field_schema().
   */


   function myfield_field_schema($field) {
   return array(
   'columns' => array(
       'code' => array(
           'type' => 'varchar',
           'length' => 2,
           'not null' => FALSE,
       ),

   ),
   'indexes' => array(
       'code' => array('code'),
   ),
   );
   }
   ```
3. In  myfield.module file add the following code

   ```
   /**
     * Implements hook_field_info().
     */
    function myfield_field_info() {
   return array(
       'myfield' => array(
           'label' => t('My Field'),
           'description' => t('This field stores a Field data in the database.'),
           'default_widget' => 'myfield_field',
           'default_formatter' => 'myfield_default',
       ),
      );
   }

    /**
    * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
     */
       function myfield_field_widget_info() {
   return array(
       'myfield_field' => array(
           'label' => t('Select list'),
           'field types' => array('myfield'),
       ),
         );
      }

       /**
       * Implements hook_field_settings_form().
       */
    function myfield_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data) {
   $settings = $field['settings'];
   // Add your global settings fields here
   $form = array();
   return $form;
     }

      /**
      * Implements hook_field_instance_settings_form().
       */
    function myfield_field_instance_settings_form($field, $instance) {
   $settings = $instance['settings'];
   // Add your instance settings fields here.
   $form = array();
   return $form;
    }

     /**
        * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
      */
      function myfield_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
   //Getting the select list.

   $options = get_all_nodes();

   switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
       case 'myfield_field' :
           $cc = "IN";

           $element['myfield'] = array(
               '#type' => 'fieldset',
               '#title' => $element['#title'],
               '#tree' => TRUE,
               '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_model_div">',
               '#suffix' => '</div>',
           );
           $element['myfield']['code'] = array(
               '#type' => 'select',
               '#title' => t('Node'),
               '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['code']) ? $items[$delta]['code'] : '',
               '#options' => $options,
               '#required' => $element['#required'],

           );

           break;
       }
       return $element;
      }


     /**
      * Implements hook_field_presave().
        */
     function myfield_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
   foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
       if (isset($item['myfield']['code'])) {
           $items[$delta]['code'] = $item['myfield']['code'];

       }
           }
    }

    /**
       * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
     */
     function myfield_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
   if (empty($item['myfield']['code'])) {
       return TRUE;
       }
       return FALSE;
       }

       /**
       * Implements hook_field_validate().
        */
      function myfield_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
   // Loop through field items in the case of multiple values.
   foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
       if (isset($item['code']) && $item['code'] != '') {
           if (!valid_myfield($item['code'])) {
               $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
                   'error' => t('Field.'),
               );
           }
          }
        }
        }

      /**
       * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
        */
      function myfield_field_formatter_info() {
   return array(
       'myfield_default' => array(
           'label' => t('Default'),
           'field types' => array('myfield'),
       ),
       );
      }

        /**
            * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
          */
         function myfield_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
   //Getting the select list values
   $options = get_all_nodes();
   $element = array();
   switch ($display['type']) {
       case 'myfield_default' :
           foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
               if (isset($item['code'])) {
                   $element[$delta]['#markup'] = $options[$item['code']];
               }
           }
           break;
          }
          return $element;
         }


     //To list out all functions
      function get_all_nodes() {
        $cflags = db_select('node', 'cf')
           ->fields('cf', array('nid', 'title'))
           ->condition('cf.status', 1, '=')
        ->condition('cf.type', 'books', '=')
           ->execute();

       foreach ($cflags as $row) {
           $options[$row->nid] = $row->title;
         }
             return $options;
     }
   ```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Followed same solution ? and is working ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://materializecss.com/badges.html#dropdown The have a pretty straight forward way of creating a dropdown menu, including code examples.

If it's for a certain Form ID you can use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` to specify which ID and alter it's HTML inside `$form_state`. If you don't know it's structure you can `var_dump($form_state);` first instead so you know what to alter.

P.S. also add the CSS of course: `drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'custom') .'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.css', 'theme', 'screen,projection', FALSE);`